# What MOSFET voltage do I need for half-bridge buck DC/DC converters connected in series?

Tags: dc

Could you please help me to understand and learn the following open point for me?

I am planing to connect about 100 1.5kV isolated DC/DC based half-bridge based adjustable power supplies 0-5V in series in order to achieve about 500V in total.

The DC/DC converters are fully isolated 1.5kV, but the MOSFETS in the half-bride operating in PWM mode are rated for maximum 60V (drain to source.) Is this a problem since there is no common ground, or they need to be rated for 500V and above?

The HV potential on the last cell will be 495V, is this a problem for MOSFET with DS 60V?

The idea is to create a 100 channel battery cell simulator device.

[image]

Comment: The idea is to create a 100 channel battery cell simulator.

Comment: (to exercise chargers&management systems?)

Comment: yes, it will provide 5v to all channels, mimicking 100 cells connected in series

Comment: (I see an earth symbol at the - output terminal of converters labelled to be 10 V from + of one to - of the other and shudder some more.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance you’re right, each supply should only ‘see’ its local 5V.  However, you’ve shown no output capacitors or other power conditioning, so it’s not hard to imagine a situation where all but one of the FETs are switched on and the only one that’s off will be exposed to the full output voltage; if there’s any significant capacitance across the output then this will end badly.  On the other hand, if there’s plenty of capacitance and some way of preventing each 5V supply from going over voltage then it should be fine.

Comment: The image is for illustration propose only, the L and C of output filter (PWM) is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

MOSFET voltage is fully bounded by their (local) supply and body diodes, even when both FETs are turned off.  (When one or the other is on, or alternating, it's further bounded by Rds(on).  I'm guessing this would be the case, i.e. synchronous operation is intended.)

Therefore either you need a local load to absorb charging power, mismatch along the stack, etc., or synchronous DC-DC isolators to transfer that power back to the bulk (15V) supply (which in turn needs some dissipation capability, perhaps using another battery pack).

Note that batteries are capable of extreme fault currents (and depending on chemistry, may be equally capable of absorbing such).  If you are simulating this aspect as well, you will need quite high capacity for all modules in the system, even if the average or nominal rating is more modest.

If only operated in discharge mode (battery sourcing current), continuous power absorption is not needed, though you may still want a TVS on each supply, to allow for incidental cases like one channel not operating, or if there can be some delay between the enables to each module.  (A TVS won't last long under such conditions, anyway (dissipating some amperes of load current, perhaps a hundred milliseconds); if such overvolt failures are rare, and if maintenance will consist of swapping modules, you might not care anyway, and let the MOSFET(s) (and other circuitry) fail.)